# Equality test in R with seq

Tags: r

Look at this simple R code:

```
seq(0.3, 2, 0.01)[56]
## [1] 0.85  
seq(0.3, 2, 0.01)[56] == 0.85
## [1] FALSE
```

Why do I get this and what's the best way to do such equality test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `all.equal` as in

```
all.equal(seq(0.3, 2, 0.01)[56],0.85)
```

This occurs because of issues in representing numbers less that 1 in binary. In general, 0.85 cannot be written exactly in binary, and the approximation used by simply typing 0.85 is not identical to the approximation used by adding an approximation of 0.01 to an approximation of 0.3 55 times.

For more details see here:
[Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

Comment: That makes sense.> print(seq(0.3, 2, 0.01)[56], digits=17)
[1] 0.85000000000000009
> print(0.85, digits=17)
[1] 0.84999999999999998

Comment: "In R 0.85 cannot be written exactly in binary" That's not R specific.